# 35mm film camera's (minolta, freedom 1) reverse sound won't stop going. Help please?

Tags: 35mm

I wanted to take out my film from my camera. I pressed the reverse button on the bottom of the camera and this is where my problems started. It made the noise but the number wasn't going down and the number still didn't go down. I eventually went into a dark room to check the film. The film wasn't reversed. The number at some point went to s, but still was making the noise. I ended up taking out the film and reversed it myself. But it's still making the noise. I tried to put in more film to see if that would change anything, but it hasn't. I'm not sure what I have done or broken or if there is something I can do. Please let me know or have any advice. I've taken the film out before, but the camera is relatively new and can't remember if I did something different before.